# 'X jobs available' should link to the available jobs anchor, not the company page

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

The featured company section shows the number of jobs available, for instance:

[image]

Clicking on the job available takes me to the company page. Instead, it should anchor me down to the available jobs.

For instance, looking at the company on-site, instead of taking me to:

https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/companies/on-site

It should take me to:

https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/companies/on-site#jobs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix pushed to production, thanks for the report!

Comment: This still doesn't work...

Comment: You're quite right, it works on regular Careers but in the SO jobs tab it doesn't because it went and appended a bunch of utm_ params to the end of the URL. Fixing :/

Comment: @JonH fixed now. Apologies for the delay.

Comment: @DeanWard This doesn't work again. It looks like the URL anchor (the ID for the "open jobs" element) has changed. It should link to `https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/company/COMPANYNAME#open-jobs`, but it currently is missing the `#open-jobs` bit at the end.

Comment: @TylerH I can't repro from ads within /jobs (that's what this post was for). Was this an ad on another part of the site?

Comment: @DeanWard I was just on StackOverflow proper (I have long since closed the tab, unfortunately). It was a featured ad for The Washington Post on the right sidebar that said "2 Current Jobs" or something of that nature, and it linked to the WaPo company page, instead of straight to the anchor link of the jobs section.

Comment: @TylerH thanks, will bring it up with the ads team!